# Consume a third-party API protected with Oauth2 in Django

Tags: python, django, api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to access a third-party API with my Django app to post some information to that API. This API supports OAuth2 authentication only and I am trying to build a Oauth2 client of consume an existing library. I found lots of solutions to implement an Oauth2 server (which is not what I needs) and some solutions to enable Oauth2 login in Django (which is not what I need either). Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when using OAuth2 with Django, its not really Django doing the work, its python. There are a number of resources for python to access API with OAuth2 authentication. [Python-Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) provides a useful tool for accessing RESTful APIs and supports OAuth2 authentication.

Comment: Thanks,

http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html

Just what I needed :)